# Why calls to super() in constructor returns void

Tags: typescript

Is there a particular reason why calls to the super() in the constructor returns `void` instead of the type of the same class?

Source: [TypeScript specs 4.9.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.9.1)

Example: [See example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IButton%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isWorking%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Button%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20config%3A%20IButton%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(config%3F%3A%20IButton)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.config%20%3D%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20RoundButton%20extends%20Button%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(config%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20work%20around%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20super(config)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20var%20me%20%3D%20this%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20me%20%3D%20super(config)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(me.config.isWorking)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C%3D%3D%3D%20Property%20'config'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'void'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F....%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%201000)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: If it returned something, it would have to be `this`. But what would be the point, since `this` is already available in the subclass constructor, from which you're calling super().

Comment: Why would you want it to return anything but void? It would only be a partially-initialized class instance anyway, therefore not valid yet. The important thing, and the only necessary thing, is that `new` returns the instance after all constructors have been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to find the documentation, but if the `super` call returns a different `this` then this new value will become `this` for the rest of the call. This is the behavior mandated by the ES 2015 specification. If you look at the generated code, you will see that the return value of `super` is used as `this` in the rest of the constructor:

```
function RoundButton(config) {
    // _this will either be the current this or whatever is returned by _super.call
    var _this = _super.call(this, config) || this;
    // refercens to this are replaces with _this
    _this.config.text = '....'; // <=== Property 'config' does not exist on type 'void'.
    return _this;
}
```

Since this behavior is already mandated, you are not free to do as you wish with the return value of super, so this is probably why it returns `void` in the type system.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want it that way?

Isn't it even easier and more readable the way that it is?

```
var me = super(config);
me.config.text = '....'; // <=== Property 'config' does not exist on type 'void'.

super(config);
config.text = '....'; // <=== Easier?
```